# Efficiently Webpage to pdf conversion

Tags: python, selenium, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, weasyprint

I am trying to convert [Website](http://tdi.dartmouth.edu/) (including css and image)into pdf and save it locally. I have been trying to use a couple of python libraries like(pdfkit, wkhtmltopdf, weasyprinrt, selenium.) I tried and found this code but don't know how to use it to achieve my goal and save the file locally.

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'res.pdf')
```

Comment: Did you try print to pdf via chromedriver ?

Comment: That is a good idea but don't know how to do it.

Comment: To save webpage via Print option, you can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984698/use-firefox-print-or-save-as-features-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I Want this to work on headless Chrome. Is there any reference for that?